# Arch Linux / systemd - prevent any kind of shutdown/rebboot

Tags: linux, archlinux, systemd, system-shutdown

I'm running Arch-based Manjaro Linux and wrote myself a little update program, that starts every 7 hours and runs completely in the background. This update program is started by systemd.

What I wanna know is: How can I prevent any system shutdown/reboot during the time this program runs no matter if the user just wants to turn it off or any program wants to do so.

The best would be, if any shutdown/reboot action wouldn't be cancelled but delayed instead, so when the update program has finished its run, the shutdown/reboot continues.

My systemd parts are:

***uupgrades.timer***

```
[Unit]
Description=UU Upgrades Timer

[Timer]
OnBootSec=23min
OnUnitActiveSec=7h
Unit=uupgrades.target

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

***uupgrades.target***

```
[Unit]
Description=UU Upgrades Timer Target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes
```

and in the folder *uupgrades.target.wants*

***uupgrades.service***

```
[Unit]
Description=UU Update Program

[Service]
Nice=19
IOSchedulingClass=2
IOSchedulingPriority=7
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uupgrades
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I want to block myself from rebooting or shutdown, I alias my usual shutdown and reboot aliases to `beep;beep;beep;`.

In multiuser environments you could move the `reboot`, `shutdown` etc. binaries and move them back, when shutdown should be allowed again.
You could also temporarily move an executable shell script outputting information about the postponed shutdown possibility in place of the corresponding binaries. This script could set a flag, if a shutdown was requested.

Q&D example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "preventing reboot"
BACKUPBINARY_REBOOT=$(mktemp);
mv /bin/reboot $BACKUPBINARY_REBOOT;
FLAGFILE=$(mktemp);
echo '#!/usr/bin/env bash' > /bin/reboot;
echo '# original reboot binary was moved to'"$BACKUPBINARY_REBOOT" >> /bin/reboot;
echo 'echo request-reboot > '"$FLAGFILE" >> /bin/reboot;
echo 'echo reboot is prevented, your request will trigger later' >> /bin/reboot;
chmod 666 "$FLAGFILE";
chmod +x /bin/reboot;
echo "postponed reboot - press enter to allow it again and make up for requested reboot";
read;
mv "$BACKUPBINARY_REBOOT" /bin/reboot;
if grep -q request-reboot "$FLAGFILE"; then
  rm $FLAGFILE;
  /bin/reboot;
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

If a user with sufficient permissions to reboot the server or manipulate processes wants to stop or reboot the machine you cant stop them. That's just how linux works. You should set up permissions and accounts such that no other users have root permissions or permissions sufficient to manipulate the process or user that the process is running as.

Comment: can't I just delay the process, I don't need a DE for this, just that the shutdown holds as long my process runs?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another systemd service at `/usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/` which will be run at shutdown, and have it check if your update script is running, and if so, cancel or delay the shutdown.